# Is there a function $f(x,y)$ such that f is equal to "a" when $x>y$ and "b" when $x<y$ and "c"when $x=y$?

Tags: functions, arithmetic

First off, I am sorry if I pose my question in a clumsy manner, as I believe I am unaware of the technical expressions.

I suppose the title requires explanation:

> Simply put, I am asking whether there is a function $f(x,y)$ that indicates whether or not $x>y$, $x<y$ or $ x=y$ is true and  then returns a fixed constant ( say $a$, $b$ or $c$) value unique to each case ( i.e. in each of the 3 cases the function should return a different constant value).

e.g.

$f(x,y) = 0$ iff ( =if and only if) $x=y$

$f(x,y) = 1$ iff $x>y$

$f(x,y) = -1$ iff $ x<y$

I have tried several functions, but all seem to have problems. For example I tried the obvious

$ f(x,y ) =\frac{x - y}{| x- y|}$,

which breaks down when $x=y$ and I then tried ( in an attempt to make the result at $x=y$ finite)

$ f(x,y) = e^{-\frac{x - y}{| x- y|}}$.

This has a similar problem for $\frac{x - y}{| x- y|}$ can be both positive and negative infinity,when $x = y$ or better(?) as $x$ approaches $y$.

In fact, maybe asking for the **existence** of such a function is a bit to broad. Apart from that, of course such a function exists, one can simply define one. So I ask, can you **find** such a function. Further find such a function that can be expressed using more or less **simple operations** ( addition, multiplication, exponentiation,...).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also any pointers towards technical problems in my question, would be equally appreciated!

Comment: Such a function can't be continuous, and since a/|a| only spits out two values, rather than three, and those values are constrained, I'm pretty sure the answer is no. That said, maybe someone will come up with something I never thought of. Or maybe a proof is possible.

Comment: @ Alfred Yerger I see. Perhaps I should have specified the domain of f. Do you think the answer changes if x and y are integers. If x and y are restricted to the naturals numbers, surely continuity can't be an issue...?

Comment: It certainly opens up possibilities, but then you could just define it piecewise, and I don't think that's what you want either. You want a formula, I think.

Comment: @ Alfed Yerger Yes, that is exactly what I want !

Comment: Certainly, there are some obvious properties of $f(x,y)$. Surely, $f(kx, ky)= f(x,y)$ and $f(k+x, k+y)= f(x,y)$, where k is any real positive number. I guess this isn't all to helpful though...

Comment: I am not sure if you will consider this a non-answer, but why not just say: $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} a & x\gt y \\ b & x\lt y \\ c & x=y \end{cases}$? Why is it helpful to you to use only "simple operations", and what do you call "simple operations" anyways? After all, $|x|=\begin{cases} x & x\gt 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ -x & x\lt 0\end{cases}$, in other words, having accepted use of $|x|$, in a way, you have already accepted using cases to define functions.

Comment: In particular, do you allow use of $\lceil x \rceil$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: But $|{x} |= \sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: @ user8734617 Yes, I completely agree. It is not clear what I **personally** mean by "simple operation" and there is no reason ( other than personal preference) why I should favor the use of one piece-wise  defined function over another. But I have ! And I ask whether having accepted the abs() function as usable anyone can think of a more or less simple formula for the said function $f(x,y)$. Actually maybe I can specify further what I mean by "simple operation". I intended to find said function $f(x,y)$ in terms of other functions that my calculator can use.

Comment: Heck, my calculator (Calculator app on Mac OS X) doesn't even have abs() button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want is discontinuous, yet you want it written using "simple" functions or operations, which are all continuous wherever they are defined. (So their composition will be continuous wherever it is defined.)

It all hangs on which "simple" functions or operations you allow. I've already suggested $\operatorname{ceil}(x)=\lceil x \rceil$ and $\operatorname{floor}(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ in the comments; I've seen the other answer with the function 'signum'... That is the point: unless you allow at least one of your "simple" functions to be discontinuous, there is no solution. Once you allow one, then we can talk about how to use it for your particular purpose.

**Update:** You are asking whether we can do the same while restricting to only whole numbers. I think we can do the following way, to start with:

$$f(n)=\frac{2n+1}{|2n+1|}=\begin{cases}1 & n \ge 0 \\ -1 & n \lt 0\end{cases}, n\in\mathbb Z$$

Now you proceed with $\operatorname{sgn}(n)=\frac{f(n)+f(n-1)}{2}$ and then follow up as in @vadim123's answer... Or, directly put $pf(x-y)+qf(x-y-1)+r=\begin{cases} p+q+r & x\gt y \\ -p-q+r & x\lt y \\ p-q+r & x=y\end{cases}$. Then, solve:

$$\begin{align} p+q+r & =a \\ -p-q+r & =b \\ p-q+r & =c \end{align}$$

to get $q=\frac{a-c}{2}$, $p=\frac{c-b}{2}$ and $r=\frac{a+b}{2}$, so the final formula is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[(c-b)\frac{2(x-y)+1}{|2(x-y)+1|}+(a-c)\frac{2(x-y)-1}{|2(x-y)-1|}+a+b\right]$$

Comment: Thanks! I see. So there is a mismatch. The one function would continuous and the other is discontinuous. Does changing the domain help ( i.e. naturals)?

Comment: Normally that would be a separate question. I will need to think about it. The argument about continuity cannot be used there...

Comment: @wittbluenote I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this should work! Can't we now use the fact that $|{x} |= \sqrt{x^2}$ to make the function continuous?

Comment: Is $\sqrt{x^2} $ continuous for all real x?

Comment: You will have zeros in the denominator... It is not that they won't be continuous, they will stop being defined for all pairs of real numbers. For example, for $x-y=1/2$ and $x-y=-1/2$ we will have a problem. To answer the other question, yes: $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. Still, the formula then holds for all real $x$ and $y$, given that their difference is not equal to $-1/2$.... Anyway, Thanks a lot. It being not the prettiest formula I have seen it is still of use to me, thanks!

Comment: @wittbluenote The formula also doesn't work when $x-y$ is between $1/2$ and $-1/2$ except if it is $0$ - when I wrote it I assumed $x,y$ will be whole numbers, so will their difference. Sorry. As I said, the question in $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ are two completely different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with characteristic functions? Put
$$
\chi_E(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & (x,y)\in E \\ 0 & (x,y)\in E^c \end{cases}.
$$
The function you are looking for is
$$
f(x,y) = a\chi_{x>y}(x,y) + b\chi_{x<y}(x,y) + c\chi_{x=y}(x,y).
$$